# Is possible to print a line in development logger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

I have a some code like this users_controller.rb, I need to print line no 30 in development.log

```
line#29  def selectrole
line#30    @userrole = RolesUser.find(:all, :conditions =>["p.user_id = ? and p.status = ? ",session[:user_id], params['status']])
line#31    logger.debug print_line(30)
line#32  end
```

Can I see 30th line in my development.log like this

```
@userrole = RoleUser.find(:all, :conditions => ["p.user_id = ? and p.status = ? ", 1234, 'Active'])
```

What is the approach to write "print_line" function? Here is the my print_line code?

```
def print_line(file_name, line) 
   counter = 1
   printline = "-------- NO SUCH LINE --------"
   File.open(file_name, "r") do |infile|
      while (line_text = infile.gets)
         if counter == line
            printline =  "#{counter} :: " +  line_text    
            break
         end 
         counter += 1
      end
   end
   printline
end
```

from this function I am getting like this

```
 @userrole = RolesUser.find(:all, :conditions =>["p.user_id = ? and p.status = ? ",session[:user_id], params['status']])
```

Is their any way to find and replace the variables with their respective values?

Comment: logger.debug "foo:#{foo}". I recommend you use the debugger for that kind of tests. It enables full access to all variables.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you're primarily interested in knowing the contents of your `:conditions`, why not just do something like this:

```
def selectrole
  conditions = ["p.user_id = ? and p.status = ? ",session[:user_id], params['status']]
  logger.debug(conditions)
  @userrole = RolesUser.find(:all, :conditions => conditions)
end
```